# Looking for a good book on star stability

Tags: astrophysics, resource-recommendations, stars, stability, stellar-physics

Can anyone recommend me any resources from which I could learn about how stars maintain a stable form, maybe using some thermal and nuclear physics, and maybe fluid dynamics, but not so advanced. Something that an undergrad can read.

Comment: Stable in what sense? The convenctive versus conductive sability issue is at the high-end of undergraduate skills and is treated in every textbook on strellar structure.

Comment: Nothing that advanced, maybe something like how you can determine the size of a star in equilibrium based on what elements it has left in its core?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want something too advanced like you said in your comment I'd recommend "An Introduction to Modern Astrophysics" by Carrol & Ostile. It contains much more than stellar structure, but those parts may be as advanced as you are asking now.